# Implement sales return table

Tags: database-design

I'm building an inventory management application for e-commerce business based on cash on delivery that has around 1000 sales per day.

When a user (admin or employee) makes a new sale, they select a product from a warehouse, enter the quantity ordered and choose the status if the products are delivered or returned and for that I've added a `$table->boolean('is_delivered');` in the sales table

My sales table looks like

```
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('warehouse_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->interger('product_price');
        $table->boolean('is_delivered');
        $table->timestamps();
```

I admit that this is a terrible design and I want to do something better about returns

I was thinking to create a new `returns` tables but then I'll have to repeat myself and add the `warehouse_id`, `product_id`, `user_id`, `quantity` and `product_price` columns

Is there anything I can do to implement this?

Comment: of course, you can try. For example, you can create additional table "SaleStatus" and put there all possible statuses,e.g. "Ordered","Shipped","Delivered","Cancelled","Returned". Then add the foreign key between your "Sales"-table and "SaleStatus"-table

Comment: @Sergey thanks but I only need two statuses delivered and returned. Wouldn't it be better if I just keep the status column in the sales table instead of doing this?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you need these two statuses only today,tomorrow your customer will come to you and tell that he can not live without status "Shipped" (just an example). On your place I would create this additional table

Comment: That makes sense. So you suggest I create a sale_statuses table with the mentioned four columns and add a sale_status_id as a foreign_key in the sales table, right?

Comment: not "four columns", but "four rows"

Comment: One more question. In this case, why can't I just make the status column integer instead of boolean and 1, 2, 3 and 4 would means the the status is either ordered, shipped, delivered or returned. What do you think?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Status column should be integer